# How to correctly require lua packages using interactive lua or torch session?

Tags: lua, torch, luarocks

I'm having difficulty installing and requiring packages in general. For example, for the inspect.lua package, I first install via luarocks as instructed in the package (https://github.com/kikito/inspect.lua):

```
luarocks install inspect
```

Then if I start either `lua` or torch7 (`th`), I will then require it via:

```
local inspect = require 'inspect'
```

This inspect variable is always `nil`:

```
require 'inspect'; print(inspect)
```

returns `nil`.

Initially, I wasn't sure that it was returning `nil`, so when I would try, for example `inspect(1)` I would get the error "attempt to call global 'inspect' (a nil value)".

Using torch, it seems like I can use "import 'inspect'" successfully, although I'm not sure why this works and require does not.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `require 'inspect'; print(inspect)` output?

Comment: When you input Lua code in an interactive session, you should leave out the `local` (or surround your whole code with `do ... end`).

Comment: @siffiejoe, that was the error, do you want to make the comment an answer?

Comment: No time now. Will post an answer later if nobody has done so in the meantime ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credit for spotting that goes to **@siffiejoe**.

The Lua interpreter works in blocks. Every block is treated as a separate execution set. Thus, if you write:

```
local a = 5
local b = a
```

In a file, it will correctly set `b` to be equal to 5, because a lua file is treated as one big block. In the REPL, though, after the first line local variables are purged.

That simply means you either should force your code into one block:

```
do local inspect = require 'inspect'; print(inspect) end
```

Or use a global variable that persists across block executions:

```
$ inspect = require 'inspect'
$ print(inspect)
```

Comment: I was wondering why it didn't give an error, this makes it clear.